# What's the difference between `make:console` and `make:command`?

Tags: laravel

I can see `make:console` in the documentation. However, I haven't been able to find `make:command` in the documentation. Plus, the file generated by `make:command` extends from `App\Commands\Command`, which doesn't exist in my Laravel 5.1 installation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Console` is actually a Command you can call per console (artisan), the `Command` was the old type for - what is now - a `Job`, but `Command` still exists for backwards compatibility (i guess).